# What is the alternative for point separate node in blender 3.1?

Tags: geometry-nodes

Point separate node which was available in 2.93 version is not available in 3.1 version. What should I use instead of point separate node to get the same output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is call "separate geometry":

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much

Comment: You are welcome!